# Node.js sqlite readonly error while using PM2 on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, sqlite, raspberry-pi3, pm2

Everything works and app starts when I command "sudo node app.js" from putty after stop pm2.
When i reboot to raspberry, pm2 list says app status online but not reachable. Also pm2 app-error.log says Error: SQLITE_READONLY: attempt to write a readonly database errno: 8, code: 'SQLITE_READONLY'

I dont know how to handle this. Made lots of research but no success.

Node version : 9.9.0

pm2 version : 4.2.3

sqlite3: ^4.1.1,

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database("./db.db", sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => { 
  if (err) { 
      console.log('Error when creating the database', err) 
  } 
})
```

Comment: what are the permissions of your sqlite DB file ?

Comment: I don't know how to learn, where to learn or how to change. can you help?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you call your app.js without sudo?

Comment: Yes I'm getting the same error

Comment: Read this, it might help : https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html

Comment: Yeah it helps. Permission of the db file was --rw-r--r-- and I changed to -rw-rw-rw-. Now its works without problem. Thanks all of  you a lot.